# WHERE clause condition checking for NULL

Tags: sql

let's say I have a table with columns `ID`, `Date1` and `Date2` where `Date2`can be `NULL`. I now want to have an SQL statement that ignores `Date2` if it is `NULL`.

So I need something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  [myTable]
WHERE
  ID = @someId
  AND Date1 <= GETDATE()
  AND Date2 >= GETDATE() IF Date2 IS NOT NULL
```

So I want to check if Date2 is not `NULL` and then compare it with the current date. If it is `NULL` then I just want to ignore it.
Hope my request is clear and understandable.

Cheers
Simon

Comment: `Date2 >= GETDATE()` this condition **already** implies it's not `null`

Comment: @zerkms that's not true. Comparisons with `NULL` are poorly defined in SQL.

Comment: @kirelagin: "So I want to check if Date2 is not NULL and then compare it with the current date" --- `Date2 >= GETDATE()` will never be true for `Date2` `IS NULL`, so another check is not required

Comment: @zerkms I get no result if `Date2` is `NULL`.

Comment: @zerkms Results of comparisons with `NULL` are implementation dependant. In fact most implementations will return `NULL`, not `FALSE` as you might expect. Then you'll do `AND` on boolean and `NULL` and so on. Never compare with `NULL`, ok?

Comment: @kirelagin: don't treat me as a dumb please. Author asked: "So I want to check if Date2 is not NULL and then compare it with the current date.". It makes no sense to add more checks as long as you already have `Date2 >= GETDATE()` since it would be true **ONLY** if `Date2` `IS NOT NULL`

Comment: zerkms - op said that he wants to ignore Date2 if it is null, therefore the null check is necessary.

Comment: @zerkms Question “Is it NULL?” implies true/false answer. `NULL` is not an answer to this question.

Comment: @PeteGO: what does "to ignore Date2" mean?

Comment: @zerkms “ignore” means “do not check any other conditions involving this column”.

Comment: @zerkms - "to ignore" means "not allow it to prevent results from being returned" in this context.

Comment: @kirelagin: hm. Perhaps I missed some relational algebra terminology changes. But ok, now it makes sense indeed

Comment: @PeteGO: I see now - it's just poorly worded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AND Date1 <= GETDATE()
AND (Date2 IS NULL OR Date2 >= GETDATE() )
```

or

```
AND Date1 <= GETDATE()
AND COALESCE(Date2, GETDATE()) >= GETDATE()-- which means : if Date2 IS NULL say Date2 = GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

`AND (Date2 >= GETDATE() OR Date2 IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
ISNULL(Date2, GETDATE()) >= GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this sql a try.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE ID = @someId
    AND Date1 <= GETDATE()
    AND (Date2 IS NULL
    AND Date2 >= GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  [myTable]
WHERE
  ID = @someId
  AND Date1 <= GETDATE()
  AND Date2 NOT IS NULL
  AND Date2 >= GETDATE();
```